# Microsoft Graph returns 400 when querying default photo

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm querying the user's photo metadata and then use the ID from the metadata to query the actual photo:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user id>/photo` returns

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('<user id>')/photo/$entity",
    "@odata.mediaContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "@odata.mediaEtag": "W/\"...\"",
    "id": "default",
    "height": 64,
    "width": 64
}
```

Note that its ID is `default`. When I then try to get the content using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user id>/photos/default/$value`, graph returns HTTP 400 with

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorInvalidImageId",
        "message": "The image ID is not valid",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-12-02T14:59:49",
            "request-id": "...",
            "client-request-id": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

If I replace `default` to `64x64` (the photo's dimensions from the metadata) in the above URL, everything's fine, i.e. `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user id>/photos/64x64/$value` returns the photo.

For many users the ID returned from `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user id>/photo` looks like `64x64` and this sort of IDs always work.

Why does Graph return `default` for some users and how should I handle it? Is it safe to create the an ID from width and height whenever I get `default`?

Answer (score 1):

We may refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-the-metadata-of-the-photo) to find the reason for this scenario.

If we call the url `/users/<user id>/photo` to get the metadata of the photo, we will get `profilePhoto` as the [response object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/profilephoto?view=graph-rest-1.0) which contains `id, height, width` and the id is made up of height and width.

Then let's see [this feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#get-the-metadata-for-a-specific-photo-size) of the api, it is designed for querying the metadata with a specific photo size, so if the id stands for the photo size, we can use id as the query parameter, but if the id is some other value, it will not work here.

**My idea** on your case is that **the api is designed for using photo size as the query parameter and we may always use the height and the width as the query parameter all the time** so that we don't need to check if it returns a correct id for querying.

[image]